# Возможно ли поменять цвет у данного SVG элемента?

Tags: css, svg

Имеется такая SVG иконка анимированная, возможно ли поменять ее цвет? Пробовал менять свойство `fill` у самого SVG элемента, не вышло, пробовал менять свойство `stroke` у `.line`, тоже результата нет, если меняю свойство `fill` у `.line` то появляются кракозябры. В чем проблема тут?

```css
.ham3 {
  fill: #fff;
}

.ham3 .top {
  stroke-dasharray: 40 130;
}
.ham3 .middle {
  stroke-dasharray: 40 140;
}
.ham3 .bottom {
  stroke-dasharray: 40 205;
}
.ham3.active .top {
  stroke-dasharray: 75 130;
  stroke-dashoffset: -63px;
}
.ham3.active .middle {
  stroke-dashoffset: -102px;
}
.ham3.active .bottom {
  stroke-dasharray: 110 205;
  stroke-dashoffset: -86px;
}

.line {
  fill:none;
  transition: stroke-dasharray 400ms, stroke-dashoffset 400ms;
  stroke:#000;
  stroke-width:5.5;
  stroke-linecap:round;
}
```

```html
<svg class="ham ham3" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="80" onclick="this.classList.toggle('active')">
  <path
        class="line top"
        d="m 70,33 h -40 c -11.092231,0 11.883874,13.496726 -3.420361,12.956839 -0.962502,-2.089471 -2.222071,-3.282996 -4.545687,-3.282996 -2.323616,0 -5.113897,2.622752 -5.113897,7.071068 0,4.448316 2.080609,7.007933 5.555839,7.007933 2.401943,0 2.96769,-1.283974 4.166879,-3.282995 2.209342,0.273823 4.031294,1.642466 5.857227,-0.252538 v -13.005715 16.288404 h 7.653568" />
  <path
        class="line middle"
        d="m 70,50 h -40 c -5.6862,0 -8.534259,5.373483 -8.534259,11.551069 0,7.187738 3.499166,10.922274 13.131984,10.922274 11.021777,0 7.022787,-15.773343 15.531095,-15.773343 3.268142,0 5.177031,-2.159429 5.177031,-6.7 0,-4.540571 -1.766442,-7.33533 -5.087851,-7.326157 -3.321409,0.0092 -5.771288,2.789632 -5.771288,7.326157 0,4.536525 2.478983,6.805271 5.771288,6.7" />
  <path
        class="line bottom"
        d="m 70,67 h -40 c 0,0 -3.680675,0.737051 -3.660714,-3.517857 0.02541,-5.415597 3.391687,-10.357143 10.982142,-10.357143 4.048418,0 17.88928,0.178572 23.482143,0.178572 0,2.563604 2.451177,3.403635 4.642857,3.392857 2.19168,-0.01078 4.373905,-1.369814 4.375,-3.392857 0.0011,-2.023043 -1.924401,-2.589191 -4.553571,-4.107143 -2.62917,-1.517952 -4.196429,-1.799562 -4.196429,-3.660714 0,-1.861153 2.442181,-3.118811 4.196429,-3.035715 1.754248,0.0831 4.375,0.890841 4.375,3.125 2.628634,0 6.160714,0.267857 6.160714,0.267857 l -0.178571,-2.946428 10.178571,0 -10.178571,0 v 6.696428 l 8.928571,0 -8.928571,0 v 7.142858 l 10.178571,0 -10.178571,0" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

При смене `stroke` вроде как все вполне меняется:

```css
.ham3 {
  fill: #fff;
}

.ham3 .top {
  stroke-dasharray: 40 130;
}
.ham3 .middle {
  stroke-dasharray: 40 140;
}
.ham3 .bottom {
  stroke-dasharray: 40 205;
}
.ham3.active .top {
  stroke-dasharray: 75 130;
  stroke-dashoffset: -63px;
}
.ham3.active .middle {
  stroke-dashoffset: -102px;
}
.ham3.active .bottom {
  stroke-dasharray: 110 205;
  stroke-dashoffset: -86px;
}

.line {
  fill:none;
  transition: stroke-dasharray 400ms, stroke-dashoffset 400ms;
  stroke:#0f0;
  stroke-width:5.5;
  stroke-linecap:round;
}
```

```html
<svg class="ham ham3" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="80" onclick="this.classList.toggle('active')">
  <path
        class="line top"
        d="m 70,33 h -40 c -11.092231,0 11.883874,13.496726 -3.420361,12.956839 -0.962502,-2.089471 -2.222071,-3.282996 -4.545687,-3.282996 -2.323616,0 -5.113897,2.622752 -5.113897,7.071068 0,4.448316 2.080609,7.007933 5.555839,7.007933 2.401943,0 2.96769,-1.283974 4.166879,-3.282995 2.209342,0.273823 4.031294,1.642466 5.857227,-0.252538 v -13.005715 16.288404 h 7.653568" />
  <path
        class="line middle"
        d="m 70,50 h -40 c -5.6862,0 -8.534259,5.373483 -8.534259,11.551069 0,7.187738 3.499166,10.922274 13.131984,10.922274 11.021777,0 7.022787,-15.773343 15.531095,-15.773343 3.268142,0 5.177031,-2.159429 5.177031,-6.7 0,-4.540571 -1.766442,-7.33533 -5.087851,-7.326157 -3.321409,0.0092 -5.771288,2.789632 -5.771288,7.326157 0,4.536525 2.478983,6.805271 5.771288,6.7" />
  <path
        class="line bottom"
        d="m 70,67 h -40 c 0,0 -3.680675,0.737051 -3.660714,-3.517857 0.02541,-5.415597 3.391687,-10.357143 10.982142,-10.357143 4.048418,0 17.88928,0.178572 23.482143,0.178572 0,2.563604 2.451177,3.403635 4.642857,3.392857 2.19168,-0.01078 4.373905,-1.369814 4.375,-3.392857 0.0011,-2.023043 -1.924401,-2.589191 -4.553571,-4.107143 -2.62917,-1.517952 -4.196429,-1.799562 -4.196429,-3.660714 0,-1.861153 2.442181,-3.118811 4.196429,-3.035715 1.754248,0.0831 4.375,0.890841 4.375,3.125 2.628634,0 6.160714,0.267857 6.160714,0.267857 l -0.178571,-2.946428 10.178571,0 -10.178571,0 v 6.696428 l 8.928571,0 -8.928571,0 v 7.142858 l 10.178571,0 -10.178571,0" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Очень странно, видимо когда у себя тестировал, не туда прописывал)

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi, возможно, либо файл не сохранял